# Customized search block

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search, ajax

I have a requirement in which there are two fields for search. One is text field and other is select box. The text field is for keywords and the select field are taxonomy terms. I need to fetch the values in both fields from text file and it should be autocomplete and display the results accordingly.

Please Help.
Thanks in Advance

Riya

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module. This module alters the default search box in many ways. If you need to have options available like in advanced search, but directly in the search box.

The module adds options to select:

- which content type(s) to search, which specific module search to use
  (node, help, user or any module that implements search),
- advanced criteria For all these choices, there are options to switch between a
  select box, checkboxes or radio buttons,
- You can also customize the selector label and the default `- Any -` text.